# Not updating the row number properly. Attributing the last created point with "1" & vice versa

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

We have to capture the sample points in survey maps. While doing so, we are facing a peculiar problem. Our survey points start from left to right <- along the survey lines. Once we have captured all the points, say 86 points and update the ID filed using $rownum-1 (to include zero), what QGIS does is it takes the last created point as the first and attributing it with **ID = 0 (which should be 85)** and the first created point as **ID = 85 (which should be 0)** . I've attached an image to explain the same.

1) $ID is not that much effective for our line of work. Coz at times we might miss some points and delete some and to update points with $ID is creating confusion.

[image]

Comment: How do you capture a point or generate the points. The first created point will have the lowest rownum.

Comment: That's why i am confused too. Pls see the image (Right click -> open it in a separate window, so that you can see it in full resolution). Exactly that's the problem we are facing right now

Comment: Did you digitize those points by hand? Should not matter, but try to draw a line in a line table where you want the points. Then from Processing Toolbox use the GRASS function v.to.points. This function will generate the points with a specified distance along the line. The points generated will have the lowest rownum starting from the start (first) vertex of the line.

Comment: Yes. Points will be in the survey maps. It's not following a pattern and so we can't generate points with specified distance between them. Currently i am digitizing those points in Mapinfo just to avoid this rowid error